# Asp.net check for session timeout every server request

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, session-timeout

I am working on a web application which uses ASP.NET membership and ASP.NET login controls to handle logging in users.  When someone logs in I store an integer value in the session to identify which company the user belongs to.  This value is used in almost all queries that are made to the database within the application.  The problem is that this value stored in the session times out after about 20 minutes but the user remains logged in to the application.

I can check if the session variable has timed out by doing

```
If Context.Session.Item("CurrentClientID") Is Nothing Then
 ' session has timed out
 ' I can reset it in here
End If
```

What I'd like to know is how I can do this check at every server request,  I use a lot of ajax so putting a check in the master page would not be suitable.  I tried putting it in the Application_BeginRequest section of the global.asax file but this causes a problem when the user is on the login page but not yet logged in, also it fires many times for each page load (fires for each css and js file loaded)

Comment: I am just curious, what is the need for the lifetime of the user's login to be greater than the session lifetime?  I think it would make this a simpler problem if the user's login expired when the session expires.

Comment: So I'd need to check on each server request if the session has timed out and if so logout the user and redirect to the login page, this could be done in the master page.  This application however makes heavy use of ajax.  Would I need to check for the timeout in each asxh file.  How would I handle logout and redirect in this case.  I'd go with this solution if the ajax problem could be solved but would still like to know if there was a way to solve the original question.

Comment: It may not be as bad as you think. A single check in your api controller's base class could be used to handle this for your ajax calls server side (you would return a specific http status code for this condition). For handling how the client reacts to this condition for ajax calls, you can register a central handler ($(document).ajaxError(yourHandler)) that can perform the appropriate action based on whichever status code you've chosen.  If you have a SPA, then this is probably all you'll need. Otherwise you'd need handling per page too, but again could go in a base class or master page.

Comment: If that sounds like it might work for you then I can add an answer along those lines, maybe with some small concrete example.  What are your server endpoints for the ajax calls, are they webapi endpoints by any chance?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay and thanks for taking the time to reply.  All my ajax calls are to generic handlers (ashx) files.  It's not a single page application but I do make use of a master page where I could register the central handler.  I'm not experienced enough to know how to go about performing the server side check in the base class though.  If you could show me how to do this in an answer that would be great.  Many thanks.